# Арабские числа-иероглиы

Tags: java, android, double

Есть приложение под андроид которое выполняет простые радиолюбительские расчеты. За последнюю неделю поймалось около десятка багов вида

```
Exception java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "۲٫۴۰"
Exception java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "٤٦٫٣٠"
```

все EditText поля заданы с такими атрибутами

```
inputValue.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
```

подскажите что может быть не так?

Comment: гляньте [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18672522/5330439)

Comment: то есть режим ввода, определяемый inputValue.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL); не гарантирует использование только числовой клавиатуры?

Comment: попробуйте определить язык, поджключите клавиатуру на телефоне, попробуйте ввести. Вы через fabric перехватываете эти exceptions? На каком андроиде и каком устройстве возникает такая ошибка? Мб это древний android. не умеющий работать с такими флагами?

Comment: перехватываю через Firebase Crashlytics. Телефоны Samsung Модель: SM-J320H и HUAWEI Модель: KIW-L21. Android 5.1.1 и 6.0.1 соответственно. Не думаю что их можно считать древними. Буду пробовать способ из первого ответа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это у вас арабские цифры, вот они и не парсятся по нормальному.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    String Numtoconvert="٨٧٫٥٩٨" ; // integer value 87.598
    getUSNumber(Numtoconvert);
}
private static String getUSNumber(String Numtoconvert){

    NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
      try {
          if(Numtoconvert.contains("٫"))      
          Numtoconvert=formatter.parse(Numtoconvert.split("٫")[0].trim())+"."+formatter.parse(Numtoconvert.split("٫")[1].trim());
          else
              Numtoconvert=formatter.parse(Numtoconvert).toString();
      } catch (ParseException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return Numtoconvert;
}
```